# Unable to add content element in neos 1.1 beta2

Tags: neoscms

I have a neos setup with version 1.1.0 Beta2.
When I try to add new content element,I get following js error.
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined on ContentModule-built.js with line 389
This happens only if page loaded via ajax.
If I reload the page then i am able to add contents and everything goes fine.
Could you please let me know the issue ?

Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

This is solved with the Neos 1.1 stable release.